# Make a smart chapter command that adjusts horizontal width based on title width

Tags: chapters, two-column

I'm currently testing a two column layout in a document using the `book` class. I would like to change the behaviour of the `\chapter` command. Right now, a short chapter title produces a lot of horizontal white space (as in this example): [image: Current output of my MWE.]

Is it possible to let the `\chapter` command check the length of the chapter title and, if shorter than the `\columnwidth`, make the chapter with a width of just one column instead of both? To be extra clear, in my MWE I would like the right column to start at the same height as the chapter title.

Here is the code that produced this image:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt,openany,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm,%
    left=25mm,right=25mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[plainfootsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{0.1ex}
\setfootsepline{0.1ex}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}%
    {\thechapter}\hspace{0.8ex}\textcolor{lightgray}{\fontsize{35}{0}%
    \selectfont |}\hspace{0.8ex}}{0ex}{\Huge\bfseries}

\makeatletter
\titlespacing*\chapter{\z@}{\z@}{2em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Results}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: 1. Use a package that allows changing column number on the fly. 2. Put your chapter-title inside a box and measure its width.
3. Use `\ifdim` to decide where to put `\chapter`: inside `twocolumn` or outside it.

Comment: Thanks for this scheme. Unfortunately, I don't think I'm sufficiently skilled in LaTeX to execute it... At least, it would take me lots of time which, at the moment, I don't have.

Comment: @PacificOrion: Is this question still of interest to you?